# Package conflict when installing cx_freeze on anaconda

Tags: python, dependencies, anaconda, cx-freeze, failed-installation

I am trying to install the cx_freeze using anaconda prompt. Following what's on their website, I used:

```
conda install -c pyzo cx_freeze
```

I get this error:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
- cx_freeze
- wincertstore
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

Does anyone know how I have to deal with dependencies here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So as of now, simply using `pip` worked for me. I opened the `conda` prompt and used the following:

```
pip install cx_freeze
```