# Make an executable file exe from a Python project

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, cx-freeze

I have a project in Python that works when executed with an audio file and other parameters using the command prompt. I want to skip all the steps to execute it and get a final project with an executable file `.exe`.
I tried to use `cx_Freeze` but I can't install the library by pip or conda commands as I get these errors:

```
$ pip install cx_Freeze
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
  File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 44, in <module>
    from .util.queue import LifoQueue
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._vendor.urllib3.util.queue'

$ conda install -c pyzo cx_freeze
Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - cx_freeze
  - win_inet_pton
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

I'm using Windows 10 and Anaconda Python version 3.7.

Any suggestions? What can I do?

Comment: Do not use code snippets for python code. It is only for HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

Comment: Do you require the `win_inet_pton` package? If not you can create a different Anaconda environment for this project. If you're not tied to `cx_freeze`, I can recommend [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/). I've had more success using pyinstaller to create executables.

Comment: thank you . i'm new here and it's my first time asking ..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Package conflict when installing cx\_freeze on anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50801992/package-conflict-when-installing-cx-freeze-on-anaconda)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when trying to compile my python projects into .exe, the issue here is the windows os has a dll file that replaces an old C++ redistributable, and theres some code in it that isn't there that is needed for the system to compile to .exe, I have not found a solution to this in my exploration